# How to keep track of a users input in C/C++

Tags: c, input, addition

I need to add to one to the variables at the bottom every time the user choses the language they prefer. If you can help me complete this tally it would be very helpful. When I run the script all I get is a 0.0000 for all variables at the bottom.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char ye;
    int lang;
    float clan=0, java=0, pyth=0, mat=0;

    printf("Favorite programming language C(1), Java(2), Python(3), Matlab(4): ");
    scanf("%d", &lang);

    printf("Continue (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c" ,&ye);

    while (ye == 'y')
    {
        printf("Favorite programming language C(1), Java(2), Python(3), Matlab(4): ");
        scanf("%d", &lang);

        if (lang == '1')
        {
            clan=clan+1;
        }
        else if (lang == '2')
        {
            java=java+1;
        }
        else if (lang == '3')
        {

            pyth=pyth+1;
        }
        else if (lang == '4')
        {

            mat=mat+1;
        }

        printf("Continue (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c" ,&ye);
    }

    printf("C: %f\n",clan);
    printf("Java: %f\n",java);
    printf("Python: %f\n",pyth);
    printf("Matlab: %f\n",mat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lang == '1'` should be `lang == 1` and the same for all the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the mentioned issue with comparing and int to a character, you also have a bug here:

```
printf("Favorite programming language C(1), Java(2), Python(3), Matlab(4): ");
scanf("%d", &lang);

printf("Continue (y/n): ");
scanf(" %c" ,&ye);
```

As you can see, you skip the first user input without incr. any of the options.

A cleaner way to handle the first pass through the loop would be something like this (as you can assume the user will have wanted at least the first pass if they launched the program). Note the initialization of `ye`, change to `int` for your tallys, and arguably better indentation and method of incrementation pointed out in some other answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    char ye = 'y';
    int lang;
    int clan=0, java=0, pyth=0, mat=0;

    while (ye == 'y')
    {

        printf("Favorite programming language C(1), Java(2), Python(3), Matlab(4): ");
        scanf("%d", &lang);

        if (lang == 1){
            clan++;
        }
        else if (lang == 2){
            java++;
        }
        else if (lang == 3){
            pyth++;
        }
        else if (lang == 4){
            mat++;
        }

        printf("Continue (y/n): ");
        scanf(" %c" ,&ye);
    }

    printf("C: %d\n",clan);
    printf("Java: %d\n",java);
    printf("Python: %d\n",pyth);
    printf("Matlab: %d\n",mat);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean

```
if (lang == 1)
```

not

```
 if (lang == '1')
```

you entered an int not a char

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're using `int` variables but you're checking the conditions on character values (`char`) which actually have an integer value, but it's not the one you think of: they're actually their [***ASCII value***](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html). For example, '1' ASCII value is 49, that's the reason you're not getting the desired result.

What you probably want to do is to check if the value of `lang` equals to 1, 2, etc., which you can achieve with the following condition:

```c
if(lang == 1) {
  // do smth
}
```

There are also other issues with your code, for example that you're declaring `clan`, `java`, `pyth` and `mat` variables as `float` but using them as integers.

Instead of `java = java + 1` you could use C increment operator: `java += 1;` or `java++;`

Last but not least, I suggest you to choose an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and stick with it, because it makes your code more readable.